# Sonata Page when landing on / If user is already authenticated redirect to dashboard /profile/

Tags: symfony, dashboard, sonata

I dont have a controller action for homepage because Sonata Page is mandatary. But when user is already authenticated and return to the root / (basically the homepage), I want that new homepage for a authenticated user became his dashboard (address /profile/) That's why  I figured out a redirection from homepage (/) to dashboard (/profile/).

Where/How can I put this redirection? (and avoid a javascript redirection)

Thanks for any help

Comment: I found a related question that can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046565/customer-home-page-sonata-page

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a redirection, just in your configuration file add your default target path :

```
firewalls:
  secured_area:
    form_login:
        always_use_default_target_path: true
        default_target_path: /loggedinpage
```

Comment: Not work! This work for user just logged in (redirected to /profile/ in my case). But if user again come to the homepage / there is not a redirection on his dashboard (/profile/). That's what I'm trying to do. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it
You just create your action :

```
/**
 * Home page
 *
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function homeAction()
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (is_object($user) and $user instanceof User) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('sonata_user_profile_show');
    }

    return $this->render('YourBestBundle:Template:template_home_layout.html.twig');
}
```

then on database "page__page" table you search for homepage route with parent_id=null and in column "route_name" where was "page_slug" selected (means handled by sonata page) you replace with your new Homepage route "homepage" (from homeAction() ) . That's it